# Can .NET XmlSerializer class deserialize InnerXml as a string?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I have a very specific deserialization need, see example below:

say I have following class:

`[Serializable]

public class Person {

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string PersonXml { get; set; }

}`

and following XML

```
<Person>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <PersonXml><someXmlFragment>text</someXmlFragment></PersonXml>
</Person>
```

What I want is the XmlSerializer class to deserialize InnerXml of the <PersonXml> element to the PersonXml property as a string.
I'm wondering if it can be done.

NOTE:
I know I can encode the content of <PersonXml> escaping illegal XML chars, but I would prefer to leave the inner XML more human friendly (not containing &lt; and other entities that will only cofuse my end user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always implement `IXmlSerializable` and do whatever you fancy through `XmlReader`.

Comment: Right, I did not consider such path.
This would definitely solve my problem, although I was hoping for some cheaper solution :)
Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you don't need [Serializable] for XML serialization. [XmlElemenht("Name")] can be omitted too, since in this particular case it does not change XMLSerializer's default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

So, even though the  element actually contains XML elements, you want .NET to pretend it is really a string? I don't think this is possible through standard serialization.

However, you could load the XML, transform the PersonXml and properly escape it and then replace the contents of the PersonXml with the newly escaped data. It would involve manually manipulating the XML before deserializing it, but then you could keep the XML elements under the PersonXml.

Comment: Yeah, but this seems to me like too much hassle and a pretty ugly solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I stumped upon this answer while searching for similar solution. Didn't want to use IXmlSerializable.

So, for reference if anyone is looking at this problem in future, you can use `XmlAnyElement` attribute to serialize inner xml as XmlNode. You can then post process the XmlNode as you see fit, run serialization separately or just get the text of xml as needed.

For this example:

```
public class Person 
{

  public string Name { get; set; }

  [XmlAnyElement]
  public XmlNode PersonXml { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Also worth adding the [XmlText] attribute to PersonXml. This will include and text nodes that are children of the node

Comment: This is a neat trick. Solved my issue of not being able to serialize a property that is an interface.
<br/>
`[XmlIgnore]
IMyInterface Thing {get;set;}
<br/>
[XmlAnyElement("Thing")]
public XmlNode ThingSerializer { get; set; } // put code in here to translate the object under your interface to/from XmlNode`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use XML to represent XML? Just use `XmlElement` for `PersonXml`.

It's always a bad idea to pretend that XML is the same thing as String.

Answer (score 0):

The post is old, but as I was looking for a solution and perhaps my answer could help someone.

What about

```
[XmlText]
public string PersonXml { get; set; }
```

This will not solve your problem but perhaps it might be an acceptable alternative.

In my case the PersonXml is a "nice-to-have-element" which does not always contain Xml. [XmlText] causes PersonXml to be null when PersonXml contains Xml. However when PersonXml contains text with no Xml the deserialization is correct.

In my case without [XmlText] the Xml in PersonXml causes elements before PersonXml to be correctly deserialized but elements after PersonXml are incorrectly deserialized.